# Can not replace a hardcoded value with a property in a csproj

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a csproj loading fine with the following lines (it is an VSTO project file):

```
...
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
        <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{20A848B8-E01F-4801-962E-25DB0FF57389}" OfficeVersion="14.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/w" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
...
```

Due to some reasons I want to set the HostPackage property of the ProjectProperties from a variable, not hardcoded so I replaced the lines with:

```
...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <HostPackageValue>{20A848B8-E01F-4801-962E-25DB0FF57389}</HostPackageValue>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
        <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="$(HostPackageValue)" OfficeVersion="14.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/w" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
...
```

As far as I know this should work the same as there are no real changes on the code but for some reason I am getting the following error when I try to reload the project

> The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Any insight about what can be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any insight about what can be the cause?

That because **anything inside of a ProjectExtensions element will be ignored by MSBuild**, so we could not use MSBuild to replace the hardcoded value with a property.

See [ProjectExtensions Element (MSBuild)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycwcwzs7.aspx) for the detailed info.

Comment: Great thanks. Do you think there is a way to overcome this limitation? Could I write conditionally the whole ProjectExtensions node with a Task or something?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia, Before I post this answer, I have the same question as you, but I could not found any workaround to overcome this limitation(Not sure if any other magic can do it). Because either a task or other something still need to be supported by MSBuild. It seems we can only modify this element out of VS, but the immediate problem is that VS throws an unsupported exception. That is the reason why I did not add any workaround in my answer :( .

Comment: I've tried to add the ProjectExtensions  in a targets file to import it conditionally but for some reason it is not working :\